# Creating set of two Divs at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I have a page with around 600px width. In this page, I want to dynamically display a Div, which itself gets header and other text dynamically. The text comes from the database. The Div looks somewhat like this and the height can vary depending upon the text it contains.

The table from which this dynamic Div is to be displayed is like this:
[image]

The Div should appear as below:

[image]

It should appear as a set of two(dynamically) as far there is another record available else only one should be displayed.

I attempted this code with a sample Div, but I want to know if there is a smarter way to this:

```
HtmlGenericControl divBlock = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
divBlock.ID = "Blockdiv";
divBlock.Attributes["style"] = "width: 120px; height: auto; background-color:grey";
divBlock.InnerHtml = "<div><table><tr><td>This is sample Div</td></tr></table></div>";
```

The Form Tag in my design page contains a main Div which looks like this:

```
<div id="MainDiv" runat="server"></div>
```

I am inserting dynamically generated div inside it:

```
MainDiv.Controls.Add(divBlock);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `DataList` control to achieve that

```
 <asp:DataList runat="server" ID="NamesDL" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
 <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="header">
       <%# Eval("CustomerName") %>
    </div>
    <div class="Details">
       <%# Eval("ProcessDetails") %>
    </div>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:DataList>
```

In codebehind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   NamesDL.DataSource = getDataFromDatabase();
   NamesDL.DataBind();
}
```

Asp.net should handle the rest

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't construct this InnerHTML dynamically. You are calling them dynamic divs, but I think what you really mean, is that you have two or three static divs, and you want to control the content and visibility of each of them.

I would create the static controls on the page, and then in your codebehind, just change the text and visibility.

I would also probably create a user control for each div, and then you can interact with the properties of the user control from your code behind, rather than worrying about how they are displayed. The ascx (view) of the user control would control how they are presented, ie: what the table structure is, or whatever.

If instead you have a varying number of these divs, based on data in the database, I would still use a usercontrol, but set them up in some sort of repeater or list control that you bind to your datasource.